# How to Save Pre/Postprocessing with ONNX Model Using MLFlow and TensorRT Execution Provider

Tags: mlflow

I'm currently working with MLFlow to manage my machine learning models, and I'd like to save both preprocessing and postprocessing steps along with an ONNX model.

Additionally, the model should be compatible with the TensorRT execution provider. I'm aware of the option to use the pyfunc flavor for custom processing steps, but I'm uncertain if it requires me to re-implement the existing functionality provided by the MLFlow ONNX flavor, particularly regarding the specification of the execution provider.

At the moment, I log the ONNX model like this:

Currently I save it as:

```
mlflow.onnx.log_model(self, "my_model")
```

I couldn't find any examples in the MLFlow ONNX documentation that detail this process. Could anyone provide guidance or an example on how to properly include preprocessing and postprocessing within the logged ONNX model, while ensuring compatibility with the TensorRT execution provider?

[MLFlow onnx][1]
[1]: https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.onnx.html